# Error on "The value of spark.network.timeout must be no less than the value of heartbeatInterval" although they are equal

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Our testcases had been running with the following code for some time but now are failing on Jenkins:

```
lazy val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "120")
.set("spark.network.timeout", "120")
.set("spark.ui.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.ui.port", "4044")
  .setMaster("local[*]")
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The value of
spark.network.timeout=120s must be no less than the value of 
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=120s.
```

Several obvious puzzles:

- the error message is self inconsistent since the values are equal
- this is failing only on Jenkins and not on local
- the error just started occurring without changes to that section of code

Has anyone run into this error with the values actually equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this change as been introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/8eb5609d8d961e54aa1ed0632f15f5e570fa627a#diff-529fc5c06b9731c1fbda6f3db60b16aa), which according to the [issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22754) has been released as part of the 2.3.0 release.

The most likely explanation for the behavior you're observing is that you recently switched to this release on Jenkins and that probably you still work locally on a previous version, which can explain the difference and the change in behavior with a change in the code.

Regarding the inconsistency of the message, I agree. You may want to open a ticket for that (or maybe provide a patch yourself). The problem is on this line:

```
require(executorTimeoutThreshold > executorHeartbeatInterval, "The value of " +
  s"spark.network.timeout=${executorTimeoutThreshold}s must be no less than the value of " +
  s"spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=${executorHeartbeatInterval}s.")
```

As you noticed, the check is for a stricter inequality, while the message suggests a non-strict one.

Comment: awesome sleuthing!

Comment: The tooling is awesome, 5 minutes on GitHub and Jira did the trick. ;)